# How to refer to set objects in a django view from a template?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have data in a database in the form like this:

```
collection_name|manufacturer|product_type|description|image_url
----------------------------------------------------------------
Testing        |FakeCo      |Bed         |pretty nice|/img/1.jpg
Testing        |FakeCo      |Desk        |pretty bad |/img/2.jpg
Testing        |FakeCo      |Nightstand  |pretty ok  |/img/1.jpg
Testing        |FakeCo      |Draws       |pretty nice|/img/3.jpg
```

Initially, I was using a for loop to display fields from each result, which ends up with something like this:[image: this:].

For the example data set above, what I am trying to do is display only the first result from certain fields, knowing they are identical for all rows returned, and then for remaining fields only display them when they are distinct.

I tried using sets in my django view, as another answer suggested this would eliminate duplicates and solve my issue.

My django view:

```
def collection_detail(request, name=None):
    template = loader.get_template('/webapps/my_webapp/furniture_site/main_page/templates/main_page/product-detail.html')
    products = product.objects.filter(collection_name=name)
    collection_name = []
    manufacturer = []
    description = []
    image_url = []
    for product in products:
        collection_name.append(product.collection_name)
        manufacturer.append(product.manufacturer)
        description.append(product.description)
        image_url.append(product.image_url)
    collection_name = set(collection_name)
    manufacturer = set(manufacturer)
    description = set(description)
    image_url = set(image_url)
    context={'products': products}
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

My issue is, that I am unable to refer to these set items in my template.

For example, in my template using:

```
                {% for instance in products %}
                {{ instance.collection_name }} Collection <br />
                {% endfor %}
```

returns nothing, as does

```
                {% for instance in products %}
                {{ collection_name }} Collection <br />
                {% endfor %}
```

What is the correct way to refer to items returned via the view in the template?

Ultimately, I am trying to get a result like the following (note descrption and collection name only used once, and duplicate image urls not returned).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you're not passing the right data towards your template.

You need to pass on `collection_name`, `manufacturer`, `description` and `image_url` in your context.

```
context = {
    'products': products,
    'collection_name': collection_name,
    'manufacturer': manufacturer,
    'description': description,
    'image_url': image_url
}
```

Now you can access these in your template like:

```
{% for instance in collection_name %}
    {{ instance }} Collection <br />
{% endfor %}
```

Same for the others.

Comment: Ahhh, it seems so simple once someone explains it, but I would not have known h ow to figure this out for myself. Thank you! Testing now.

Answer (score 1):

It should render only one object in the loop. Still you can use **[first](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#first)** in your interpolation.

Like this:

```
{{ instance.collection_name|first }}
```

---

**EDIT**

You need to pass `collection_name` as you have initialised it as an empty list therefore it is a variable which you can use only when you pass it in `context`.

```
 context={'products': products, 'collection_name': collection_name}
```

Comment: When I tried that before using sets in my view, |first gave the first characters of each row+field, not the first result. Also, I need some fields to be multiple within the loop, such as image urls